# Dirichlet-Categorical conjugate prior model using OpenBUGS,R and the package R2OpenBUGS

Tags: r, bayesian

At first, let's create some sample categorical data with 3 levels.

```
y<-sample(c("A","B","C"),50,replace=TRUE)
```

I'm trying to formulate a Bayesian statistical model in which the y variable follows categorical distribution with parameters theta1,theta2,theta3. These parameters describe the probability a single y[i] belongs to the corresponding category. In the bayesian perspective, these parameters are also random variables and we use to assign a dirichlet prior to them with hyper-parameters alpha1,alpha2,alpha3.

I'm having some problems with the syntax as it seems.

**CODE**

```
model<-function(){
  #likelihood
  for( i in 1:N){
  y[i]~ dcat(theta[])
  }
  #prior
  theta[1:3]~ ddirch(alpha[])
}
library(R2OpenBUGS) 
model.file <- file.path(tempdir(),"model.txt") 
write.model(model, model.file)
y<-sample(c("A","B","C"),50,replace=TRUE)
N<-50
alpha<-c(1,1,1)
data<-list('y','N','alpha')
params<-c('theta')
inits<-function(){theta=c(1/3,1/3,1/3)}
```

We call OpenBUGS through R, with the bugs function

```
out<-bugs(data,inits,params,model.file,n.chains = 2
          ,n.iter=6000,codaPkg = TRUE,n.burnin = 1000,DIC = TRUE)
```

I've tried different ways to syntactically formulate the above code, dribbling through the errors and getting familiar with the log.txt file (that is the file that keeps the OpenBUGS output) until this code gave me  a log.txt with no errors while R still has problems.

**R output**

```
  Error in bugs.run(n.burnin, OpenBUGS.pgm, debug = debug, WINE = WINE,  : 
  Look at the log file in  /tmp/Rtmpofdk0t  and
try again with 'debug=TRUE' to figure out what went wrong within OpenBUGS.
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : class of 'x' was discarded
```

**log.txt**

```
OpenBUGS version 3.2.3 rev 1012
model is syntactically correct
data loaded
model compiled
initial values generated, model initialized
1000 updates took 0 s
monitor set
monitor set
monitor set
monitor set
deviance set
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerous experiments, i figured out that for some reason OpenBUGS cant accept factor variables given as usual. So i changed my data ( format "A","B","C") to numeric (format 1,2,3) with the `as.numeric` R function  and everything ran smoothly!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rename theta1, theta2, theta3 with alpha1, alpha2, alpha3, because you use the alpha1,... in the function ddirch, but you never declare them. Instead you declare theta1 and so on, but never use them.

If there are any other issues, you might have a look at the log file, like the compiler suggests.

Comment: I searched a bit more and changed a set of obvious errors ; one of them being error that you mentioned. I also used log.txt a lot to find my way . So thank you 2 times. The problem has  changed but not solved